# Bypassing max MTU

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, mtu, jumbo-frames

I'm considering upgrading my home network to a router with jumbo frame support.  Before I drop the cash on it I have a question about MTU's.

The largest MTU my current router supports is 1500.  On the other hand I have a switch that does support jumbo frames.

If the router is put into bridged mode, would I still be limited to and MTU of 1500 or would the router accept the higher MTU and pass it through to the switch?

Comment: Also keep in mind this might create significant overhead on outgoing traffic (e.g. internet), based by your ISP. Is there any specific reason you think you need jumbo frames?

Answer (score 1):

Every ethernet device on a LAN/VLAN must be set to the same frame size.  Not just your computer, but your router, your switches, and every other device.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit

> The limit varies by vendor. For correct interoperation, the whole Ethernet network must have the same MTU. [citation](https://www.stsauver.com/~joe/jumbos/jumbo-frames.pdf)